Cannot Insert Dump and Run Command Simultaneously in Docker MySQL Container
I'm trying to insert a MySQL 5.7 dump into my MySQL 8.04 container. Normally, I run this command: sudo cat file.sql | docker exec -i [container_name] mysql [database] -u[user] -p[password], and it works just fine. However, due to the version difference, I need to run:

SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;

Here's what I've tried so far:
sudo cat easy_marine.sql | docker exec -i easy_marine_db_8 mysql easy_marine -uworkbench -pworkbench -e "SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;"
sudo cat easy_marine.sql | docker exec -i easy_marine_db_8 mysql easy_marine -uworkbench -pworkbench <<< "SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;"

Each time, the terminal ends instantly as if everything worked fine, but usually, it takes around 10 minutes to complete the dump. And of course, the database was not updated...

a) you'll need a root priv to set a global variable. b) setting the global variable applies to newly created sessions. So make the import a second step without -e.

You shouldn't need either sudo or docker exec here.  If you started the database container with a docker run -p ...:3306 option, then you can use the mysql client from the host system as an unprivileged user to connect to the containerized database.  This should be exactly the same as doing this without Docker, up to a mysql -h 127.0.0.1 option.
